# Using SD card shield on Arduino Due

Tags: serial, shields, arduino-due, sd-card, spi

I have a Seeed Studio SD card shield (V3) that I am trying to use on my Arduino Due. I am having trouble using the SD examples that come with the Arduino IDE.

They worked fine on my Arduino Uno by setting `chipSelect` to `SS`. Below is the code I used for the Arduino Uno. It is the same as the `CardInfo.ino` in the examples section under SD (except for the `chipSelect`).

CardInfo.ino

    /*
      SD card test

```cpp
 This example shows how use the utility libraries on which the'
 SD library is based in order to get info about your SD card.
 Very useful for testing a card when you're not sure whether its working or not.

 The circuit:
  * SD card attached to SPI bus as follows:
 ** MOSI - pin 11 on Arduino Uno/Duemilanove/Diecimila
 ** MISO - pin 12 on Arduino Uno/Duemilanove/Diecimila
 ** CLK - pin 13 on Arduino Uno/Duemilanove/Diecimila
 ** CS - depends on your SD card shield or module.
        Pin 4 used here for consistency with other Arduino examples


 created  28 Mar 2011
 by Limor Fried
 modified 9 Apr 2012
 by Tom Igoe
*/

// include the SD library:
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>

// set up variables using the SD utility library functions:
Sd2Card card;
SdVolume volume;
SdFile root;

// change this to match your SD shield or module;
// Arduino Ethernet shield: pin 4
// Adafruit SD shields and modules: pin 10
// Sparkfun SD shield: pin 8
const int chipSelect = SS; //CHANGE HERE!!!!!!!!

void setup()
{
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only
  }


  Serial.print("\nInitializing SD card...");
  // On the Ethernet Shield, CS is pin 4. It's set as an output by default.
  // Note that even if it's not used as the CS pin, the hardware SS pin
  // (10 on most Arduino boards, 53 on the Mega) must be left as an output
  // or the SD library functions will not work.
  pinMode(10, OUTPUT);     // change this to 53 on a mega


  // we'll use the initialization code from the utility libraries
  // since we're just testing if the card is working!
  if (!card.init(SPI_HALF_SPEED, chipSelect)) {
    Serial.println("initialization failed. Things to check:");
    Serial.println("* is a card is inserted?");
    Serial.println("* Is your wiring correct?");
    Serial.println("* did you change the chipSelect pin to match your shield or module?");
    return;
  } else {
    Serial.println("Wiring is correct and a card is present.");
  }

  // print the type of card
  Serial.print("\nCard type: ");
  switch (card.type()) {
    case SD_CARD_TYPE_SD1:
      Serial.println("SD1");
      break;
    case SD_CARD_TYPE_SD2:
      Serial.println("SD2");
      break;
    case SD_CARD_TYPE_SDHC:
      Serial.println("SDHC");
      break;
    default:
      Serial.println("Unknown");
  }

  // Now we will try to open the 'volume'/'partition' - it should be FAT16 or FAT32
  if (!volume.init(card)) {
    Serial.println("Could not find FAT16/FAT32 partition.\nMake sure you've formatted the card");
    return;
  }


  // print the type and size of the first FAT-type volume
  uint32_t volumesize;
  Serial.print("\nVolume type is FAT");
  Serial.println(volume.fatType(), DEC);
  Serial.println();

  volumesize = volume.blocksPerCluster();    // clusters are collections of blocks
  volumesize *= volume.clusterCount();       // we'll have a lot of clusters
  volumesize *= 512;                            // SD card blocks are always 512 bytes
  Serial.print("Volume size (bytes): ");
  Serial.println(volumesize);
  Serial.print("Volume size (Kbytes): ");
  volumesize /= 1024;
  Serial.println(volumesize);
  Serial.print("Volume size (Mbytes): ");
  volumesize /= 1024;
  Serial.println(volumesize);


  Serial.println("\nFiles found on the card (name, date and size in bytes): ");
  root.openRoot(volume);

  // list all files in the card with date and size
  root.ls(LS_R | LS_DATE | LS_SIZE);
}


void loop(void) {

}
```

Here is a picture of my setup:

[image: Due with SD card shield]

#### tl;dr

How do I make this shield work on my Due?

Comment: One of the main differences between UNO and DUE is the voltage level: UNO uses 5V for all its pins and DUE supports only 3.3V; Is your shield able to work with 3.3V supply **AND** 3.3V logical signal levels?

Comment: I think I know what's happening. This shield is built for Uno, MEGA, and some other older boards, and it communicates via SPI. I think that I will have to use a break out board instead of a shield because the SPI pins on the DUE does not match up with the shield....Unless I can figure out some way to write to it using Serial.

Comment: Did you manage to solve your problem? If so, would you like to post the answer and accept it? If you could do so, then that it would remove this question from the unanswered list of questions.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Due Pin description]

Looking at the pin configuration, the SPI pins are not in the same location as the UNO. Remove the Shield from Due and use cables to connect to the SPI pins